# Using Wacom with PT

Tags: nuendo, pt

I got a small little Wacom tablet for Christmas and am finally getting around to trying to see how I can use it other than a penmouse :).  How are you all using tablets to control things In PT or Nuendo. I'm trying to find ways to kind of open up happy accidental sound creation.  I have seen videos on how Kyma X integrates with a tablet and thought maybe I could link it to mess with plugins and things in PT. Any tips? Any 3rd party programs that allow you to use it in a non standard manner?

I am trying to isolate it as some kind of controller in PT rather than have it move my mouse cursor, that way I can use my trackball for cursor and tablet for manipulation etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am on a mac with a litte piece of software called OSCulator (http://www.osculator.net/)

It is free to try, and cheap to buy.  This was proven to be the easiest solution for me. Just press the caps lock key and the wacom stops being a mouse and starts sending midi data.

I have used this with Reaktor and Alchemy with some pretty cool results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this software also lets you connect WII controllers via bluetooth and use them to send MIDI data.

magic wand style synth

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PT, but in Nuendo with quick controls (it's the thing where you can very quickly assign any vst parameters to selected midi controller) Intuos 4 become some sort of magic wand,  because you can control four parameters simultaneously with one hand: X/Y, pressure and pen incline as the fourth.

imho the incline of the pen is an uncomfortable controller for the midi-messages and therefore you can save your money and buy Bamboo Pen and still control three parameters at one time.

Comment: does quick controls automatically turn the pen into midi controller? or does it also move mouse at the same time.  I am using bamboo pen actually.

Comment: trying to mess around with it in nuendo, cant seem to make it a midi controller, the program wmidi only seems to be active when it is in the forground and nuendo will not learn the midi commands while nuendo is moved to the background


Comment: @Michael
I remember that wmidi didn't work on my pc and I used Borogove MIDI Tab and it worked fine. I don't actually remember how it works with mouse, but I think you don't need to control the mouse and the pen simultaneously. For quick control you have to assign proper parameter in the remote device setup. For instance quickcontrol1 - coordinate X, 2 - Y, 3 - pen pressure and later on a selected audio track you just assign a required vst parameter on aforementioned quickcontrol sections.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a little program called Wmidi.  Takes wacom tablet signals and converts them into midi.  Now to see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I use mine in PT to draw in automation a little more smoothly, as well as use it in spectral clean up software. 
Not that it speeds up work flow, but feels more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

So Ive found that using a program named Tablet 2 Midi, then using LoopBe1 as an internal midi pipeline, in combination with nuendo's quickcontrols, I can have some pretty darn cool things controlled using wacom, playing around with some screams and mondo mod currently :)

Trying to figure out how to use the 2 buttons on the pen as modifiers some how, would be cool to have x/y normal , x/y when button 1 depressed and x/y when button 2 depressed.